# Allow users to search for other users in Wordpress Frontend

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a plugin that I've created within my site, which just shows one page where I'm calling all users and then some specific information about those users.

Would it be possible to allow users to search for other existing users from the front end of the site?

This is the kind of thing I've got going on at the moment, I haven't been able to find any kind of search of this sort of thing, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it's be very much appreciated,

I haven't included any code as it's not that relevant really, but I can include it if needs be,

Thanks in advance!

http://focusedlearning.hcrlaw.com/courses-admin/

```
<?php $total_users = count_users();
$total_users = $total_users['total_users'];
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
$number = 20;?>

<?php 
    $args = array(
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'display_name',
        'count_total' => 'true',
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        'offset' => $paged ? ($paged) * $number : 0,
        'number' => $number,
    );?>

<?php
    $blogusers = get_users($args);?>

        <?php // Array of WP_User objects.
            foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {?>

<?php $userId = $user->ID;?>

<?php  echo '<input type="text" value="' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '">';?>



<div id="content">

    <h2>Completed Courses</h2>


<!-- COMPLIANCE-->



    <?php
        $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
            'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-365 days' ) ),
            'tax_query' => array(

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'compliance',
                    ),
                        ),

                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'associated_people',
                                'value' => '"' . $userid . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                    )
                ); ?>

    <!-- MEMBERSHIP A -->                       

    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 2 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

        <?php
        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

            <table style="width:100%">      
                <tr>
                    <td>Compliance</td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                    </tr>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


    <?php

    $total_credit = 0;

    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

    <table style="width:100%">      

        <?php
            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
        ?>


        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <tr>
            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP A -->


        <!-- MEMBERSHIP B -->                       

    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 3 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

        <?php
        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

            <table style="width:100%">      
                <tr>
                    <td>Compliance</td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                    </tr>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


    <?php

    $total_credit = 0;

    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

    <table style="width:100%">      

        <?php
            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
        ?>


        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <tr>
            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP B -->

        <!-- MEMBERSHIP C -->                       

    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 4 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

        <?php
        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

            <table style="width:100%">      
                <tr>
                    <td>Compliance</td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                    </tr>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


    <?php

    $total_credit = 0;

    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

    <table style="width:100%">      

        <?php
            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
        ?>


        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <tr>
            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP C -->

        <!-- MEMBERSHIP D -->                       

    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 5 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

        <?php
        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

            <table style="width:100%">      
                <tr>
                    <td>Compliance</td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                    </tr>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


    <?php

    $total_credit = 0;

    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

    <table style="width:100%">      

        <?php
            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
        ?>


        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <tr>
            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP D -->




        <!-- MEMBERSHIP E -->                       

    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 6 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

        <?php
        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

            <table style="width:100%">      
                <tr>
                    <td>Compliance</td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                    </tr>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


    <?php

    $total_credit = 0;

    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

    <table style="width:100%">      

        <?php
            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
        ?>


        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <tr>
            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP E -->


        <!-- END OF COMPLIANCE-->
```

Comment: Hi, it's possible to search users. If you can get list of users then you can apply searching and sorting as well. Please share your code there you'r facing problem.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code which is pulling in what you can see in the link, I have tried a couple of things such as adapting the Wordpress search but I've got nowhere, so any help you could give me/point me into the right direction would be great!